# String.Replace using multiple values

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, replace

I was looking at some code from a co-worker and it looks as though they're using a Char Array in their String.Replace:

```
txtPAPTransit.Text = g_aAllBranches(instApplication.branchForCumisReporting.ToLower).transit.ToString.Replace({" "c, "-"c}, "").Substring(3)
```

Which doesn't remove the "-" from the string in the textbox (the string being 123-45678). When I try it making the Substring as 4 instead of 3, it works. Which strikes me as very odd, why would it behave like this in this case when the index is 0 based?

When I write the replace like this it works fine:

```
txtPAPTransit.Text = g_aAllBranches(instApplication.branchForCumisReporting.ToLower).transit.ToString.Replace("-"c, "").Substring(3)
```

Afterwards the string appears as 45678, which is the correct result.

Why would it work in the case of replacing the substring with 4 as I mention above? And why does it have a problem with the char array?

Comment: Can you give us a sample value so we can follow along?

Comment: Why would you expect the first example to remove the "-" from the textbox? The first argument is what to remove, in that case, it would be the space that would be replaced with the -

Comment: @ScottMarcus But if you notice the .Replace has a char array in its 'oldValue' position. .Replace({" "c, "-"c,"") which if the logic were correct, would mean that it would replace either a whitespace or a dash with nothing. But the Replace doesn't seem to be able to handle this.

Comment: it doesnt remove the "-" because the Replace usage is wrong.  `{" "c, "-"c}` will equate to " " + " -" not act as a multiple replace for any space and any "-".  Thus nothing is removed.  Replace takes a single char or a string: an array of char is a string so nothing happens unless it is "123 -45678". `.Replace(" "c, "").Replace("-"c, "")` would be the way to do both/either

Comment: Tricky code for no reason. Your coworker seems to be tired of VB

Comment: @Plutonix You're so right! I just tried it out with "123 -45678" and received the correct output. I'm sort of kicking myself now that I didn't realize that was what it was looking for lol. Thanks for pointing that out! I'll let my co-worker know about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Replace` usage is not correct - or your co-workers understanding of it is flawed.  The 2 overloads are:

```
- String.Replace(Char, Char)  
- String.Replace(String, String)
```

So, `Replace({" "c, "-"c}, "")` will not act to replace any space and any dash with `String.Empty`.  Instead, since a char array **is**  a string, it will look to replace `" -"` (space+dash) as in "123 -45678".

The correct way to replace either would be:

```
Dim sample = "123- ABCDEFG"     
newTxt = sample.Replace(" "c, "").Replace("-"c, "")
```

> "123ABCDEFG"

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've got it written the proper way with the 2 Replace functions and it works great now!

Comment: Glad to help -  that long, long expression in the Q makes it hard to follow wothout an example because the "problem part" is scrolled off